# How to escape dollar sign on Docker-compose bash script command

Tags: linux, bash, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have the following container configured as part of a docker-compose script. I need to remove the prefix URL `/rooturl` and continue with the remaining part of the request. But I'm not having success because I can't escape the dollar sign ($) when the content is written to the `nginx.conf` file (the dollar sign disappears).

```bash
app-reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:1.23
    ports:
      - "9090:80"
    command: |
      bash -c 'bash -s << EOF
        cat > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf << EON
          daemon off;
          user www-data;
          events {
            worker_connections 1024;
          }
          http {
            gzip on;
            gzip_disable "msie6";
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            server {
              listen 80;
              root /var/www/html;
              index index.html;
              location ^~ /rooturl/ {
                proxy_pass http://other-app:8080;
                rewrite /rooturl(.*) /$$1 break; 
              }
            }
          }
      EON
      nginx
      EOF'
    depends_on:
      - other-app
    networks:
      - docker-net
```

I already tried to escape it using `\$$1` and `"\$$1"`, no success so far, any ideas on how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the file directly on your host.

```
# nginx.conf
daemon off;
user www-data;
http {
  ...
}
```

Since this is just a file, you don't need to escape anything.

Once you've done that, you can inject it into the container using a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).  The only thing your `command:` does is to try to create the file, and then run `nginx` as normal; since you're not creating the file, you can use the default command from the image.

```yaml
app-reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:1.23
    ports:
      - "9090:80"
    volumes: # <-- add
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    # no command:
    depends_on:
      - other-app
    networks:
      - docker-net
```

Comment: Hi, thanks David, in the end this is the approach I decided to go for. But I'm still intrigued why I can't handle the $ escape through the command in docker-compose. Just a side note, this works fine for kubernetes. :(

Answer (score 1):

We use 'EOF' to generate a file which is not changed. Try that.

cat << 'EOF' > file
echo "I love my $$$"
EOF

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried your approach but it didn´t work because of docker-compose: `ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "command" option in service "app-reverse-proxy"`. The first two $ escape the second one, but the third one is not escaped and then docker-compose tries to interpolate it as an env variable.

Comment: Did you try the apostrophes with your EON? 'EON'